# Refer to outer $it from nested loop

Tags: kotlin

I have code as follows:

```
    tt@repeat(5) {
        repeat(5) {
            // Here refer to $it from outer repeat, 
            // as well as from inner one
            print("${tt@it} $it,")
        }
        println()
    }
```

Above code does not work, and it generates warning:

> Label is redundant, because it can not be referenced in either ''break'', ''continue'', or ''return'' expression

is it possible without for example storing outer $it in some local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can modify your code like this:

```
 tt@repeat(5) { _it1 ->
    repeat(5) {
        // Here refer to $it from outer repeat, 
        // as well as from inner one
        print("$_it1 $it,")
    }
    println()
}
```

Comment: No need for `tt@` . Also the variable names could be better e.g: 

```
    repeat(5) { rowVal ->
        repeat(5) { colVal ->
            print("$rowVal $colVal,")
        }
        println()
    }
```